# Python pandas resample montly works weekly doesnot

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to define monthly and weekly ranges for stock data. Below code is only for the high and it works for the monthly but it does not for the weekly. I get all NaN when I try to create a new column in the df for the weekly. Also, if I use a variable instead of a new column , I get correct results.

```
test = df['High'].resample('w',how='max')
print test

...
2015-03-01    212.24
2015-03-08    212.06
2015-03-15    208.79
2015-03-22    211.27
2015-03-29    211.11
2015-04-05    208.61
Freq: W-SUN, Name: High, Length: 70



df['WHigh'] = df['High'].resample('w',how='max')
print df['WHigh']

...
2015-03-26   NaN
2015-03-27   NaN
2015-03-30   NaN
2015-03-31   NaN
2015-04-01   NaN
2015-04-02   NaN
Name: WHigh, Length: 336
```

Comment: Can you post your raw df['high']?

Comment: This is because you try to assign into the same dataframe: only 1 in 7 of the index values will match, the rest get NaN values.

Comment: not even 1 of 7 is getting values because resample('w') is using sunday as last day. data is stock data which has Friday as last day. I tried to use w-fri but did not get correct results.

Comment: liam just added df['high'].

Comment: I rolled back the edit, as adding all the data doesn't add anything to this question. (For future reference: the easiest way to format code is to highlight and use CTRL+K.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the original index is different from the resampled index, so you can't assign it back to the original DataFrame (as a column).

---

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
            0
2015-01-01  1
2015-01-02  2
2015-01-03  3
2015-01-04  4
2015-01-05  5
2015-01-06  6

In [13]: df.resample('W')
Out[13]:
              0
2015-01-04  2.5
2015-01-11  5.5

In [14]: df['weekly'] = df.resample('W')

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
            0  weekly
2015-01-01  1     NaN
2015-01-02  2     NaN
2015-01-03  3     NaN
2015-01-04  4     2.5
2015-01-05  5     NaN
2015-01-06  6     NaN
```

*See that only the day which matches the week representative is filled in, everything else is NaN.*

---

If you want to set all the values in that week to the mean/max use a transform:

```
In [21]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).transform('mean')
Out[21]:
            0
2015-01-01  2
2015-01-02  2
2015-01-03  2
2015-01-04  2
2015-01-05  5
2015-01-06  5
```

Note: possibly there's a bug here, it should be float IMO!

```
In [22]: df.astype('float64').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).transform('mean')
Out[22]:
              0
2015-01-01  2.5
2015-01-02  2.5
2015-01-03  2.5
2015-01-04  2.5
2015-01-05  5.5
2015-01-06  5.5
```

Comment: if that is not coercing to float in the transform (on master) pls post an issue